# WSDL error: (Salesforce integration)

Tags: parsing, soap, wsdl, salesforce, apex-code

I am currently trying to integrate ExpressionEngine and Salesforce using a SOAP API. I have a working WSDL but when I try and parse the WSDL and create APEX classes in Salesforce it ends up throwing some weird errors. I have posted extensively on this at the following salesforce forum link: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/URGENT-WSDL-Issues-Error-Failed-to-parse-wsdl-type-not-specified/td-p/548983

It was originally throwing an error saying that the name attribute could not be null so I then added name="salesforce" to the node. After that it began throwing a type error:

```
Error: Failed to parse wsdl: type not specified for attribute: salesforce
```

I have tried to debug this, but can't really find much wrong with the following declaration:

```
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Associative[]" name="salesforce"/>
```

The full WSDL document can be found at the above link. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is not my particular area of expertise and I have a fast approaching deadline.

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL is using the rpc/encoded interaction style, this is not supported by the Salesforce WSDL2Apex tool. You'll have to manually create/parse requests to this API.

Comment: Hi superfell, thank you for your input. I have read this also, and have read about converting the WSDL from an encoded interaction to a document/literal interaction. Either way however the same type error persists. If I could understand why the type not specified for attribute error is being thrown I would be relatively happy to be honest and then I could pursue changing the interaction style around properly.

Comment: would need to see the rest of the definition. in general you can't convert the wsdl to not be rpc/encoded without changing the underlying service as well.

Comment: I could send you the WSDL link if you like? What is involved exactly in manually creating/parsing requests in terms of APEX code? Are there any tutorials or general guidelines perhaps?

Comment: So what do people do instead?  Write their own HTTP calls and build their own SOAP/XML content?